# Composer Curl error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: php, ssl, composer-php

I'm trying to get composer to work on a remote Windows-machine which is using a proxy, but I always get this error when doing a composer install/update:

> [Composer\Downloader\TransportException] curl error 60 while
> downloading https://flex.symfony.com/versions.json: SSL certificate
> problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

This is my composer.bat:

```
@echo OFF
:: in case DelayedExpansion is on and a path contains ! 
setlocal DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set HTTP_PROXY=<proxyurl>
php "%~dp0composer.phar" %*
```

Obviously setting the proxy is needed, if I delete the line, the error becomes this:

> [Composer\Downloader\TransportException] curl error 28 while
> downloading https://flex.symfony.com/versions.json: Operation timed
> out after 10000 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received

`composer diag` gives me this (with the proxy set):

```
Checking composer.json: OK
Checking platform settings: OK
Checking git settings: OK
Checking http connectivity to packagist: OK
Checking https connectivity to packagist: OK
Checking HTTP proxy: OK
Checking github.com rate limit: OK
Checking disk free space: OK
Checking pubkeys:
Tags Public Key Fingerprint: 57815BA2 7E54DC31 7ECC7CC5 573090D0  87719BA6 8F3BB723 4E5D42D0 84A14642
Dev Public Key Fingerprint: 4AC45767 E5EC2265 2F0C1167 CBBB8A2B  0C708369 153E328C AD90147D AFE50952
OK
Checking composer version: OK
Composer version: 2.0.9
PHP version: 7.4.7
PHP binary path: C:\Program Files\PHP\current\php.exe
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020
cURL version: 7.69.1 libz 1.2.11 ssl OpenSSL/1.1.1g
zip: extension present, unzip not available
```

I've been through a lot of posts and tutorials, but none of the answers work for me. (Some are just about curl and it's options to switch off the cert-check but that doesn't work for composer). Here's what I have tried:

- Downloaded cacert.pem from http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem or https://curl.se/docs/caextract.html (no copy&paste as some said editing the file would corrupt it - however that's supposed to happen)
- saved the file locally
- activated openssl in php.ini
- edited php.ini and added the path of the cert-file for "curl.cainfo" as well as "openssl.cafile" (according to some posts that makes a difference, so I tried both), used the full path and quotes, like this: `curl.cainfo="C:\Program Files\PHP\cacert.pem"`
- moved the pem-file to different directories to make sure no Windows-permissions would make it inaccessible (I also set the file and it's directory to be accessible by all users just to make sure)
- used `php -r "print_r(openssl_get_cert_locations());"` to find out the default certfile-location (it's "C:\Program Files\Common Files\SSL"), also saved the cert-file there

All of this did not work, the error remains the same.
Then I found a post which set a repository in composer.json and explicitely set the certfile for that repo, so I also tried it and added this to my composer.json:

```
{
  "repositories": [{
    "type": "composer",
    "url": "https://flex.symfony.com",
    "options" : {
      "ssl" : {
        "cafile" : "cacert.pem"
      }
    }
  }]
}
```

The file "cacert.pem" is in the same directory as my composer.json, now the error is this:

> [Composer\Downloader\TransportException] The
> "https://flex.symfony.com/packages.json" file could not be downloaded
> (HTTP/2 404 )

which is not that surprising, as trying to access "https://flex.symfony.com/packages.json" via a browser also gives me a 404. (Don't know if it makes a difference that all at a sudden "packages.json" couldn't be loaded while the cert-error complained about "versions.json", have no idea which is loaded first and if this error is a "good" sign.)

This trial-and-error journey has been going on for days, I'm out of ideas, so any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Further research led me to the proxy, which is ZScaler, being the problem. As stated in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61491995/docker-windows-composer-zscaler-ssl-certificate-verify-failed) post, ZScaler intercepts SSL traffic and re-encrypts it with its own certificate which is not trusted, so Composer (or any other program accessing sites via https) will complain with the above error that it's "unable to get local issuer certificate".

So the solution must be to get the "ZScaler Intermediate Root CA" to be trusted on the server. (Which I can't do myself due to company policy, but anyone looking for a solution to the above problem probably has another hint now what to do.)

Comment: After reading this answer I entered in Windows Control Panel -> Internet Properties -Content -> Certificates -> Trusted Root..., and exported the Zscaler Root CA to a Base-64  encoded X.509 file. Then I referenced this file in php.ini (both curl.cainfo and openssl.cafile). Then it worked fine!

Answer (score 35):

i have no idea if your problem is the same as the problem i just got. but i solved it by executing this in `cmd`:

```
composer config -g -- disable-tls false
```

i'm using wamp anyway.

Comment: fine this work for me. Thanks @daddi Al Amoudi

Comment: I've disabled this setting to work on PHP 5.6 code, and totally forgot about it.

Answer (score 6):

Linux
(Paths in this guide will assume a default Linux installation on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, but it will be similar for other distros.)

1. Download the latest CA bundle extract from curl.se

   wget https://curl.se/ca/cacert.pem -O /etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem  --no-check-certificate
2. Edit your php.ini file.

For Ubuntu 18.04, there are 2 php.ini files which need to be modified in the following locations:

/etc/php//cli/php.ini

/etc/php//fpm/php.ini

Replace the  with the version of PHP you’re using, so for PHP 7.4, the path will be /etc/php/7.4/…

In these files, you need to either modify or add the curl.cainfo and openssl.cafile parameters with the path to the new CA bundle:

[curl]

curl.cainfo = /etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem

[openssl]

openssl.cafile = /etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem

(only add the parameter if it does not already exist in your php.ini file. Duplicate parameters can prevent PHP from running correctly)

3. Restart your php-fpm to load the new settings.

systemctl restart php-fpm

Replace the  with the version of PHP you’re using, so for PHP 7.4, the command will be systemctl restart php7.4-fpm

DONE!

source: (https://support.deskpro.com/is/kb/articles/how-to-update-curl-trusted-root-certificates)

Answer (score 5):

after using the `composer config -g secure-http false` and clear my composer cache using `composer clearcache` solved my problem, with WAMP server.

Answer (score 2):

If you use a symfony/flex older than 1.17.1:

```sh
composer show symfony/flex
```

then you need to update it with:

```sh
composer update symfony/flex --no-plugins --no-scripts
```

[Source](https://symfony.com/blog/upgrade-flex-on-your-symfony-projects)

Answer (score 1):

I also faced this issue, and my system is behind corporate proxy. I had tried below methods.

1. Downloaded latest `cacert.pem` from https://curl.se/docs/caextract.html.
2. Mentioned the path in respective `php.ini` file.

   ```
    [curl]
    curl.cainfo = "PATH/TO/cacert.pem"
    openssl.cafile = "PATH/TO/cacert.pem"

    [openssl]
    openssl.capath = "PATH/TO/cacert.pem"
   ```
3. Updated composer global config to ignore certificate and TLS/SSL.

   ```
    composer config --global disable-tls true
    composer config --global secure-http false
   ```
4. Updated cafile and capath configuration of composer.

   ```
    composer config --global cafile PATH/TO/cacert.pem
    composer config --global capath PATH/TO/DIRECTORY/WHERE cacert.pem is placed
   ```
5. Saving the `cacert.pem` file as `curl-ca-bundle.crt` under `C:\Windows\System32` (I am on Windows)
6. Restarting the OS as last resort.

Unfortunately, NONE worked.

### The solution for system behind corporate proxy

Finally, I appended the root certificate provided by my organization in the cacert.pem file. It worked and the composer command was then able to download the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Yes sometime the issue encounter if system is not connected to Zscaler which is installed by company for security. Connect with Zscaler and re run the command. The issue will get resolved.

Answer (score 0):

> https://asset-packagist.org could not be fully loaded (curl error 60
> while downloading https://asset-packagist.org/packages.json: SSL
> certificate problem: certificate has expired), package information was
> loaded from the local cache and may be out of date

I am facing this Issue while `composer install` on `Yii2` Project Operating System `Windows` and `Wamp` 
I update the Certificate using this Video [SSL certificate](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wxNi6x2LYvI&t=7s) on Wamp 
Still facing same issue at last I update the composer using command `composer self-update` Everything works fine I update composer version from `2.1.8` to `2.2.7`

Comment: I'm getting the same error again!

Comment: can you help explain more. Issue is fixed and occur again?

Answer (score 0):

Update keys using:

`composer self-update --update-keys`

Then follow the instructions (copy and paste the key from https://composer.github.io/pubkeys.html)

Answer (score 0):

Even this an old question and has many answers I found myself that none of them worked for me. In my case I've a local development environment using [Docker](https://github.com/wodby/docker4drupal), so using some sort of OS-hack would not work since is not persistent and furthermost cannot be passed down to any of my teammates (yes I know I could have my own image but does not worth the effort). The issue was raised while using the [assets-packagist](https://asset-packagist.org/) repository.

I solve this using this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35767253/composer-self-signed-cert), and for that I downloaded the [cacert.pem](http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem) at my project root dir and bound it to my container and set the repository as follows:

```
"assets": {
   "type": "composer",
   "url": "https://asset-packagist.org",
   "options": {
       "ssl": {
          "verify_peer": true,
          "allow_self_signed": true,
          "cafile": "/var/www/html/cacert.pem"
       }
   }
}
```

This way any composer command work and trust in the registry certificate.

Answer (score -2):

It seems you made the mistake of going on the wrong path

If you are using PHP version php7.4.21

CORRECT :  Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.21

WRONG :  Applications/MAMP/config/php7.4.21