# curl error 60 while downloading https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: laravel, composer-php

tried to run below command to create a new project:

```
$ create-project laravel/laravel react-js
```

and got the following error:

```
 curl error 60 while downloading https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json:
SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

composer diagnose output as below.

```
Checking platform settings: OK

Checking git settings: OK

Checking http connectivity to packagist: OK

Checking https connectivity to packagist: FAIL
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException] curl error 60 while downloading https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

Checking github.com rate limit: OK
Checking disk free space: OK
Checking pubkeys: FAIL
Missing pubkey for tags verification
Missing pubkey for dev verification
Run composer self-update --update-keys to set them up
Checking composer version: FAIL
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException] curl error 60 while downloading https://getcomposer.org/versions: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
Composer version: 2.3.5
PHP version: 7.4.29
PHP binary path: C:\php742\php.exe
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.1n  15 Mar 2022
cURL version: 7.70.0 libz 1.2.12 ssl OpenSSL/1.1.1n
zip: extension present, unzip not available, 7-Zip not available
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Is your system date-time sync?

Comment: @A.Seddighi Yes

Comment: add `"disable-tls": true,` in your composer.json config

Comment: or you can even try `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel react-js`

Comment: @GurudasBodke: Please see this Q&A: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66276070/367456 , could it be there is a proxy intercepting the traffic? https://stackoverflow.com/a/66366341/367456

Comment: This is just an error message. You should probably share a bit more of your understanding of it so that it becomes more clear what you're asking about. And please add the output of `composer diagnose`  to your question.

Comment: You are probably missing the cacert.pem file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cURL error 60: SSL certificate: unable to get local issuer certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29822686/curl-error-60-ssl-certificate-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate)

Comment: @HassaanAli thanks for reply, but its not work, showing same error.

Comment: @hakre thanks for the response, I have added output of composer diagnose

Comment: composer config -g -- disable-tls true